Dynamic filter for data in Datagrid on ASP.NET side
I have an ASP.NET page with Ajax and a datagrid (datatables). The datagrid has search fields in the columns.
For the normal search field, the data from the data source is filtered as follows:
myData = myData.Where(m => m.myFieldA.Contains(searchValueA)
                           || m.myFieldB.Contains(searchValueB)
                           || m.myFieldC.Contains(searchValueC));

I want to build the filter dynamically. I get the field names and the search terms via a loop. Now I would like to design the filter dynamically and generate it according to the entries in the search input fields.
If something has only been entered in 2 fields, the filter should only filter on the 2 entries and alternatively link with and, or according to the user's specifications.
How can you make
m.myFieldA.Contains(searchValueA) 

dynamic? Is it something like this:
m.fields("myFieldA").Contains(...

Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with it yet.

The search in Datatables plugin does not work like what you have mentioned. what ever you have added in the search box of datatables plugin, If handled in back-end with with all columns then search will return result matching search from all columns. If you limit two two columns then search will be done in only two columns. It depend on your choice. you can either handle filtering or sorting at back-end business logic layer or you can do it at database level. I recommend looking into ASP.NET MVC & Datatables JQuery Plugin Server Side Integration article for better understanding. This example uses datables ajax. I hope it helps.
